# How to use lifetimes when capturing a &str in a builder pattern?

Tags: rust, lifetime, builder

I am working on a random text generator which is going to store a "pattern" for output (among other parameters), and I think `&str` is the right data type given that the user of my library will specify the pattern in his code.  I'm using a "Builder" pattern to build a "Generator" struct, and I want to specify that the pattern will outlive both the builder and generator.  Here's my code without lifetime parameters:

```
pub struct Generator {
    pub pattern: &str,
}

impl Generator {
    pub fn builder() -> GeneratorBuilder {
        GeneratorBuilder::new()
    }
}

pub struct GeneratorBuilder {
    pattern: &str,
}

impl GeneratorBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pattern: "",
        }
    }
    pub fn with_pattern(mut self, pattern: &str) -> Self {
        self.pattern = pattern;
        self
    }
    pub fn build(&self) -> Generator {
        Generator {
            pattern: self.pattern,
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler at this point tells me I need lifetime specifiers in both struct definitions, and if I follow its recommendations I end up with `'a` and `'_` and `'static` at various places throughout my code.  But this will not compile.  The code now is:

```
pub struct Generator<'a> {
    pub pattern: &'a str,
}

impl Generator<'_> {
    pub fn builder() -> GeneratorBuilder<'static> {
        GeneratorBuilder::new()
    }
}

pub struct GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
    pattern: &'a str,
}

impl GeneratorBuilder<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pattern: "",
        }
    }
    pub fn with_pattern(mut self, pattern: &str) -> Self {
        self.pattern = pattern;
        self
    }
    pub fn build(&self) -> Generator {
        Generator {
            pattern: self.pattern,
        }
    }
}
```

The error I end up with is "lifetime may not live long enough" in the definition of function `with_pattern` because "assignment requires that [pattern] must outlife [self]".  My question is: **Where do I need lifetime specifiers, and which ones do I need, to tell Rust that the str called "pattern" will live longer than the Generator and the GeneratorBuilder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is just use `'a` everywhere:

```rust
pub struct Generator<'a> {
    pub pattern: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Generator<'a> {
    pub fn builder() -> GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
        GeneratorBuilder::new()
    }
}

pub struct GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
    pattern: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pattern: "",
        }
    }
    pub fn with_pattern(mut self, pattern: &'a str) -> Self {
        self.pattern = pattern;
        self
    }
    pub fn build(&self) -> Generator {
        Generator {
            pattern: self.pattern,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will require you to keep the builder in a variable as well as the output. E.g. `let g = GeneratorBuilder::new().build();` [doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=51085ad304f4007a42f8ff1e73d0d437).

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more detailed on which lifetimes are used at each stage. In particular you need to:

- Tell the compiler that `Generators` created with the default pattern have a `'static` lifetime. This is done by having `new` return `GeneratorBuilder<'static>`
- Tell the compiler which lifetime is used for the created `Generator` in `GeneratorBuilder::build`. There are two possibles, either the lifetime of the `&'_ self` reference or the lifetime embedded in the `GeneratorBuilder<'_>`. By default the compiler takes the lifetime of the reference but you want the other one: `fn build<'b>(&'b self) -> Generator<'a>` (the `'b` lifetime can actually be omitted here, I've just added it to make the distinction more explicit).

Complete working example:

```
#[derive (Debug)]
pub struct Generator<'a> {
    pub pattern: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Generator<'a> {
    pub fn builder() -> GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
        GeneratorBuilder::new()
    }
}

pub struct GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
    pattern: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> GeneratorBuilder<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> GeneratorBuilder<'static> {
        GeneratorBuilder {
            pattern: "default",
        }
    }
    pub fn with_pattern(mut self, pattern: &'a str) -> Self {
        self.pattern = pattern;
        self
    }
    pub fn build(&self) -> Generator<'a> {
        Generator {
            pattern: self.pattern,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let g = GeneratorBuilder::new().build();
    println!("{g:?}");
    
    let g = GeneratorBuilder::new().with_pattern ("foobar").build();
    println!("{g:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=eade9623e0282a80ab6e4644a2c83cd7)